# Re-Downloading Linux (Kernel) Source

Tags: linux, download, kernel

yesterday i downloaded source of my virtual linux kernel and tried to compile it. 
It compiled indeed but could not boot from the new kernel.

Then today i decided to re-downloading after removing the folder where source files are located but it said "linux source is already the newest version"

I use the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

What should i do to be able to re-download the source.

thanks...

Comment: Shouldn't this be on user error or server fault?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you did something that you should never do. You manually erased an installed package.

Try `apt-get install -f linux-source`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-source
```